# UNTIL LOOP in shell for read file

Tags: bash, loops

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
cat days.txt | while read days
do
    echo $i $days
    let i++
done
```

I want to change while loop into until loop

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
until conditions
do
    echo $i $days
    let i++
done
```

expected result

1. Monday
2. Tuesday
3. Wednesday
4. Blah Blah Blah

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Reading your question it's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Please add a paragraph or two describing your problem and use case. The code example you provided also looks a bit incomplete to my eyes. I you need more in depth guidelines, please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Simon Your comment looks very standardised (I see it in this form very often) -- is there a place where to copy and paste these comment from?

Comment: @Simon I run until.sh in Unix OS and I have days.txt in same directory

Comment: OK I ask again. change while loop into until loop please.

Comment: @l'L'l if my question is duplicate , why my problem still exist. Help me please.

Comment: @ThomasKühn No, I just wrote it up actually. I came here from post triage (which I think you cannot access with reputation ≤ 2500), but I recall seeing some form av guidelines along those lines in there.

Comment: @Craze You specific problem might very well exist even though your question is a duplicate. In order for questions (and answers) to be useful to others they should be as broad and generic as possible, rather than "solve this problem for me please" posts.

Please do look into [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) which attempts to answer those questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while read` can be written more awkwardly as `until ! read`:

```
i=1
until ! read -r days; do 
    echo "$i $days"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done < file
```

`while command` does something as long as `command` exits successfully, whereas `until command` does something until `command` exits unsuccessfully. The `!` is used to negate the exit code of `read`.