# how can i use until loop read text file (bashshell)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What Should i do i am a beginner

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
cat days.txt | until [ ! $i -le 7 ] read item
do
        echo $i $item
        let i++ 
done
```

This is the result I want.
1 Monday
2 Tuesday
3 Wednesday
4 Thursday
5 Friday
6 Saturday
7 Sunday

Comment: How does this question look so much like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44281184/until-loop-in-shell-for-read-file)?

Comment: @Inian days.txt are contains monday tuesday wednesday ...

Answer (score -1):

```
i=1
while read item
do
    echo $i $item
    i=$((i+1))
 done <./days.txt
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.